# Way to format strings with "?" parameters to full string in java?

Tags: java, string, logging, parameters, format-string

For example I want to implement class with method

```
public class Logger {

    public void info(String message, String[] params) {
    }
}
```

If input is

```
new Logger().info("Info: param1 is ? , param2 is ?", new  String[] {"a", "b"});
```

Output must be

```
Info: param1 is a , param2 is b
```

What is the easiest way to implement it?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the standard String.Format method?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`String.format(String format, Object ... args)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method for this. Instead of using a `?`, you can do C style `%x` format, where `x` can be `d` (for int), `s` (for string), etc.

[Example](http://www.matsuvp.com/blog/2011/java-string-format-examples-formatting).

Also, you can view the [`Formatter.format`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) class method. It shows you all formatting flags acceptale for formatting (`String.format()` method uses `Formatter` to do the formatting).

Comment: Your link no longer works. This is why Stack Overflow asks you to include relevant material within your Answer.

Answer (score 5):

The following code does as you require.

```
public class Logger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Logger().info("Info: param1 is ?, param2 is ?", new String[] { "a", "b" });
        new Logger().info("Info: param1 is ?, param2 is ?", "a", "b");
    }

    public void info(final String message, final String... args) {
        System.out.printf(message.replace("?", "%s") + "%n", args);
    }

}
```

However, you should consider using correct formatting place-holders instead of '?'. For instance:

```
 public class Logger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Logger().info("Info: param1 is %s, param2 is %s", new String[] { "a", "b" });
        new Logger().info("Info: param1 is %s, param2 is %s", "a", "b");
    }

    public void info(final String message, final String... args) {
        System.out.printf(message + "%n", args);
    }

}
```

Both versions will print:

```
Info: param1 is a, param2 is b
Info: param1 is a, param2 is b
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to worry about escaping the `'?'`, and you can't use printf() style format strings, you could get away with:

```
public void info(String message, String[] params) {
    System.out.println(
        String.format(message.replace("?", "%s"), params)
    );
}
```

Like so:

```
info("apple is to ? as eve is to ?",
    new String[] { "banana", "noon" });
```

Which prints: `apple is to banana as eve is to noon`

---

If you need more sophisticated logic, such as escaping, then you'll probably want a full-blown regexp `Pattern`-based search and replace.

Comment: Ok, the output prints only to `System.out`. What if the OP wants to log the error to a file using a logging framework?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, then I think the OP should be using a logging framework instead of trying to write one himself/herself.

Answer (score 0):

in a loop on params[] use regexp to find every '?' in your string and substitute it with the current param. Beware of nulls and find a proper way to escape ? (guess \? will give some trouble, better ??)